# How can I supply a valid class to a method with a parameter of Class<? extends Annotation>?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

I have a situation where I need to programmatically set something that has a parameter of `Class<? extends Annotation>` but I cannot figure out how to pass in an Annotation class to this method.

For example, if I have `javax.persistence.Entity` and I try `setAnnotation(javax.persistence.Entity.class)` I get an error saying `Class<Entity>` is not applicable for those arguments. However, that is a class that has the `@interface` attribute; it's obviously an annotation. What am I doing wrong and how can I appropriately send in a value?

The reason for this is I'm going from Spring XML configuration to class `@Configuration`. It's easy enough to do this in an xml file with:

```
<property name="annotation" value="javax.persistence.Entity" />
```

but I don't know what Spring is doing to make that work.

```
public class Stuff {
    private List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations;

    public List<Class<? extends Annotation>> getAnnotations() {
        return annotations;
    }

    public void setAnnotations(List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations) {
        this.annotations = annotations;
    }
}

public class StuffTest {


    @Test
    public void test() {

        new Stuff().setAnnotations(Collections.singletonList(javax.persistence.Entity.class));
        // this does not compile
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(javax.persistence.Entity.class);
stuff.setAnnotations(list);
```

works but is there a better way?

Comment: Could you post an SSCCE? Because the scenario you described above should work just fine.

Comment: Sure, give me a few. I should note the actual scenario is a list of these, but I'm not sure how that would complicate the matter.

Comment: @Perception Ah, type erasure on the list is screwing it up for some reason... the list is the reason why it's failing. But how can I fix it?

Comment: Just got into work so couldn't respond, but +1 for the amended question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the API that works for me (both using the Eclipse and javac compilers):

```
public void setAnnotations(
  Collection<? extends Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations) {
```

Of course, this would mean you'd have to change some of the inner workings of `Stuff` itself...

Note also the `Collection` argument type, as `Collections.singleton()` returns a `Set`, not a `List`. Maybe you meant to use a `Collections.singletonList()` instead?

Comment: I can't change the stuff so I'll have to use the untyped list, but this is a correct approach so I will accept it.